# How to manage a list of hosts, refresh their status regularly to make sure all the hosts in the list can be reached

Tags: python, multithreading, dht

I'm implementing a DHT protocol Kademila with Python recently.
http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html

But I don't know how to implement this is a high efficiency way:

- *A good node is a node has responded to one of our queries within the last 15 minutes. A node is also good if it has ever responded to one of our queries and has sent us a query within the last 15 minutes. After 15 minutes of inactivity, a node becomes questionable. Nodes become bad when they fail to respond to multiple queries in a row. Nodes that we know are good are given priority over nodes with unknown status.*
- *When the bucket is full of good nodes, the new node is simply discarded. If any nodes in the bucket are known to have become bad, then one is replaced by the new node. If there are any questionable nodes in the bucket have not been seen in the last 15 minutes, the least recently seen node is pinged. If the pinged node responds then the next least recently seen questionable node is pinged until one fails to respond or all of the nodes in the bucket are known to be good. If a node in the bucket fails to respond to a ping, it is suggested to try once more before discarding the node and replacing it with a new good node. In this way, the table fills with stable long running nodes.*

This rule shows how to refresh Nodes in the Buckets: A Node will be pinged if not hearing from it in 15 minutes to determine whether it is still a good Node.

How Can I implement the rule above?
Should I set a timer for each Node? If I hear from it in 15 minutes, the timer for this Node will be reset. If the time is out, the Node will be added to a ping queue waiting to be judged.

But I don't have a good idea to implement this in Python, Could any one give some guidance?
Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BEP5 is fairly concise, omitting a lot of details, it is recommended to also read the [original Kademlia paper](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/~petar/papers/maymounkov-kademlia-lncs.pdf)

As for state-keeping: For each routing table entry you can keep a time when it has last responded to a query (last seen message is insufficient due to asymmetric reachability caused by NATs).

You can simply run a timer that enumerates your routing table, let's say every 10 seconds, looking for questionable entries to ping/bad entries to remove if replacements are available.
You can also trigger pings on insertation attempts into a bucket's replacement list.

How exactly you perform maintenance (event-driven, timer-based, proactive pinging vs. mostly passive operation piggybacking maintenance on remote requests) is not all that important to the Kademlia algorithm.
The goal is to not serve unreachable entries from your routing table and to keep your home-bucket region up to date to compenssate for churn.

Since you tagged this as multi-threading: The routing table's tree and the main bucket lists should be fairly stable. So you can use copy-on-write data structures (read snapshot without lock, modify under lock). The replacement lists are modified more frequently, so a concurrent queue might be more useful.

But normal DHT nodes don't experience much traffic anyway. 100 packets per second would already be an unusual peak. This could all be handled on a single thread.
You only really need multiple threads for multi-homed, server-class nodes with low latency and high reliability which may - over time - end up in lots of other node's routing tables.

You could also look at existing implementations:

- [C](https://github.com/jech/dht/blob/bf62643a954f83a1d0b44712c62f22adfbfdd8b6/dht.c) - jch's libdht, used by transmission
- [Java](https://github.com/the8472/mldht/blob/91be220c9b0cc39c3dc75c49107358a241d7b85e/src/lbms/plugins/mldht/kad/Node.java) - my own implementation
- [C++](http://libtorrent.org/) - libtorrent-rasterbar, a bittorrent library that also contains a dht implementation and has python bindings

Comment: What you said inspired me a lot. Thanks.